# Regular Expression alternation not working

Tags: javascript, regex

Good afternoon

I am testing my Regular Expression on regex101.com site.
Regular Expression:

```
<button[^<]*>.*[\s\S]*<\/button>|
<iframe[^<>]*\/>|
<tr>[^<td>]*<\/tr>
```

Test Text

```
<table width="30px">
<P>Teste</p><iframe src="teste" /><p>Test</p>
<div><span>Teste Regex</span></div>
<p>Test</p><button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
<table>
<tr><td>34</td></tr>>
</table>
```

Why only the `<button[^<]*>.*[\s\S]*<\/button>` code is matched ?
If i clear this part of the regular expression and stay only with this:

```
<iframe[^<>]*\/>|
<tr>[^<td>]*<\/tr>
```

Only the `<iframe..` is matched

Why is this happen and how can I fix it ?

Comment: If this is any kind of production system or has any security responsibility I strongly recommend you dont use regex to parse/clean HTML - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Why you shouldn't try to parse HTML with regular expressions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-reg

Comment: The users of the application can make Copy and Paste to a rick Text Editor on our apllication, some times the users select all text from a page , and inadvertently copy buttons , javascript etc.
When we show on otjer page the text inputed by the users , this text throw erros because contain those button and iframes codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the new lines before your OR and also set the **G** (global flag).

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/gE5bK7/1)**

[image]